# How to get the request messages from a website

Tags: web-scraping

I want to be able to get the source video link for each video from tiktok.com. I found that you can see each request in chromes network panel and the link to the source video (request URL). How would be able to make a program that intercepts these requests and adds the request url to a list of some sort? Thanks.

[chrome network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph8DC.png)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you read more about `web-scraping`

To receive video links, you can send the desired request, then separate the specific part you want with `regex` or ..

for example, video link ...

If there is a feature for this topic, you can read in the official source:

https://developers.tiktok.com/

It is possible that a library or framework has already been written for this

**tiktok api**

You can read the following link and use the available repositories:

https://www.google.com/search?q=tiktok+api